# How do I mock express() to test that the gets get called?

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, chai

I have the following...

```
class CommunicationsApplication{
  constructor() {
    this.app = express()
    this.app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.send('Hello World!')
    })

    this.app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Pure PM listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
    })
  }
}
```

I would like to use mocha to test that the express().get function gets called but I am not sure how to do this. The test should be like

```
Given I run the app
When I construct the app 
Then this.app.get is called with the correct params
```

Answer (score 0):

Some testing frameworks accept a webserver to bind to and make requests against that. One example is [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest). Their README has a fairly complete walkthrough.

You'll probably want to pull the listen bind out of your constructor, initialize `CommunicationsApplication` in a before block, and then pass its `app` into each request.

To make up for this refactor, you would want to call listen on an instance of `CommunicationsApplication`'s app in your server entrypoint.

Comment: I would rather use a unit test than an integration tests that requires a lib for a fully managed server.

Answer (score 0):

You need a stub library such as `sinon`. Then, you can stub out dependencies with [Link Seams](https://sinonjs.org/how-to/link-seams-commonjs/). Unit testing:

`app.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');

class CommunicationsApplication {
  constructor() {
    const port = 3000;
    this.app = express();
    this.app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.send('Hello World!');
    });

    this.app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Pure PM listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
  }
}

module.exports = CommunicationsApplication;
```

`app.test.js`:

```js
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('69006756', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const expressStub = {
      get: sinon.stub(),
      listen: sinon.stub(),
    };
    const ExpressStub = sinon.stub().returns(expressStub);
    const CommunicationsApplication = proxyquire('./app', {
      express: ExpressStub,
    });
    const application = new CommunicationsApplication();
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(application.app.get, '/', sinon.match.func);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(application.app.listen, 3000, sinon.match.func);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
  69006756
    ✓ should pass (1525ms)


  1 passing (2s)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |      75 |      100 |   33.33 |      75 |                   
 app.js   |      75 |      100 |   33.33 |      75 | 8,12              
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```